# How to calculate the variance of a matrix column in Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

Using the Networks extension, the following two attempts to calculate the variance of Column 1 generate errors - can anyone please help?

```
variance (list matrix:get-column t_mat 1)

variance [ (list matrix:get-column t_mat 1) ]
```

Comment: I haven't used the matrix extension but `matrix:get-column t_mat 1` should return a list. So you should just need `let var variance matrix:get-column t_mat 1`. You don't need the `list` operator at all.

Comment: JenB is exactly right. Jen, you should move your comment to an answer so it can be marked correct.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the matrix extension but `matrix:get-column t_mat 1` should return a list. So you should just need `let var variance matrix:get-column t_mat 1`. You don't need the list operator at all.